# nginx subdomain redirect catches other subdomains

Tags: nginx

I'm currently running an application on a subdomain through nginx and require SSL. I implemented redirect that forces all http traffic to https on that subdomain. I noticed that `http://www.mydomain.com` is being redirected to `https://app.mydomain.com`. However, visiting `http://mydomain.com` works fine.

My goal is to have `http://www.mydomain.com` redirect to `http://mydomain.com`.

And continuing redirect all http to https traffic for `http://app.mydomain.com`.

My current nginx configuration looks like this.

```
server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
  server_name  www.mydomain.com;
  return 301 http://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
  server_name mydomain.com;
  access_log  off;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mydomain;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

My configuration for the application is like this:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /nowhere; # this doesn't have to be a valid path since we are redirecting, you don't have to change it.
    return 301 https://app.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote/close vote? How is this outside of the scope of SO and off topic?

Comment: The question seems fine with me, voted it back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason the `app` server will take priority if it for some reason matches better, the only difference I see is the `listen` line, change it from `*:80` to `80` to match the rest, and tell me if that works.
Also remove the root, it's pointless like you said, don't forget to restart/reload the service.

**EDIT**: according to you you were using firefox, firefox caches the responses, so if i set server1 to redirect to server2 and I visit server1 from firefox, firefox saves that redirect, next time it would redirect without visiting server1, to solve that you need to clear firefox cache, if you know your first visit was today for example, you can only clear today's cache, I learned this by trials

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looked like the problem was resolved on a completely different level. I was having some issues with DNS cache and once that cleared my problem was resolved.

Comment: are you using firefox?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried Chrome by accident and the problem didn't exist. I changed my DNS servers a few times yesterday and it seemed like my laptop was having issues clearing the cache (macbook air).

Comment: The issue isn't the dns directly, firefox caches the responses, so if i set server1 to redirect to server2 and I visit server1 from firefox, firefox saves that redirect, next time it would redirect without visiting server1, to solve that you need to clear firefox cache, if you know your first visit was today for example, you can only clear today's cache, I learned this by trials.

Comment: Wow, that is super helpful. I would love to mark your question as an answer. Do you want to add that to your answer and I'll mark it as the solution.